# What will be the better way for data retrieval on application that needs to handle limited amount of data?

Tags: android, xml, data, storage, sqlite

Just moved this question from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785980/what-will-be-the-better-way-for-data-retrieval-on-application-that-needs-to-hand/14786002#14786002). Since, adding my code snippets itself would make this question really long. Instead, I am pretty interested in knowing a better ways for data retrieval on application that needs to handle limited amount of data which isn't updated regularly. Let's take this example:

I am writing an application which gets a schedule as an XML from server. I have written a logic in order to parse XML version and update database only if the version is newer than the local version. Although the update is checked automatically/manually on daily basis based on user preference, the actual version update happens only once per few months or so. Since, this is done by some other authority which doesn't provide API but, rather inform publicly on their changes.

The actual XML contains a "(n number of groups)(days in a week) (n number of schedule)" . The group is usually 6 and the number of schedule is usually 2. So basically there would usually be only around 100 strings.

Now although I have used SQLite at the moment. I want to know how to make update on database. **Should I show progress dialog that the application is updating and exit the app when it's done?** Since, my updates are infrequent i don't think this will really harm user experience but, **is there any better ways to do it?** Because I don't want update to be made when user is searching which is done using database. This will cause an database already open exception. At least I have faced this problem before.

Is it better to rather parse XML every time when user wants to view certain things or to use SQLite? Since, I make lots of use of adapter in my app to create lists, will that degrade the performance?